# Why won't CSS variables work with SCSS variables

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I'm trying to implement dark mode for my project. Kindly share any better way of doing this.

I have a checkbox that changes `<html data-theme="light">` to `<html data-theme="dark">`. I then use `CSS` to change the value of the variables so they can update where used.

```
// Light theme colors
html[data-theme="light"]{
   --body: #fff;
   --primary: #0077FF;
   --secondary: #3f3d56;
   --danger: #f00;
   --text: #707070;
   --el-bg: #fff;
   --border: #ddd;
   --shadow: #ddd;
}

// Dark theme colors
html[data-theme="dark"]{
   --body: #111;
   --primary: lighten(#0077FF, 10%);
   --secondary: #3f3d56;
   --danger: #f00;
   --text: #eeeeee;
   --el-bg: #222;
   --border: #000;
   --shadow: #000;
}

$body: var(--body);
$primary: var(--primary);
$secondary: var(--secondary);
$danger: var(--danger);
$text: var(--text);
$el-bg: var(--el-bg);
$border: var(--border);
$shadow: var(--shadow);
```

The issue is the `SCSS variables` won't take the values assigned from the native `CSS variables`

I've tried using `CSS variables` only but they won't work inside `SCSS functions` like `darken and lighten`

Comment: because SASS is a preprocessor that comes before CSS, CSS variable doesn't exist at this level

Comment: Any idea of achieving what I'm targeting?

Comment: you simply cannot. Either use SASS variables or CSS variables, don't mix both

Answer (score 0):

SASS/SCSS is a preprocessor. SASS variables was replaced with value.
**SASS/SCSS**

```
$red: #ff0000
color: $red
```

After compiling in CSS will be

```
color: #ff0000
```

If you want use CSS variables in SASS you must use like in CSS code:

```
color: var(--text)
```

You can tray to use classes, for example:

```css
    html[data-theme="light"]{
        --body: #fff;
        ...
        .body-color{
            background-color:var(--body);
        }
        ...
    }
    // Dark theme colors
    html[data-theme="dark"]{
        --body: #111;
        ...
        .body-color{
            background-color:var(--body);
        }
        ...
    }
```